# angular post request to a asp.net web API server

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-web-api

IN angular js i am trying to send a post request her is the controller.
    .controller('ActivationController',['$http','$location','$routeParams','AuthService',

```
function($http, $location, $routeParams, AuthService){

        var location = $location.path();
        var activation_code = $routeParams.code;
        var activationLink = "http://localhost:18678/api/User/ActivateUser";
        console.log(activation_code);
        if(activation_code){
            $http({method:"post", url:activationLink, data:activation_code}).success(function(response){
                console.log(response);
            }).error(function(error){
                console.log(error);
            });
        }

    }]);
```

and in asp.net web API her is the method.

```
 [HttpPost]
        public HttpResponseMessage ActivateUser([FromBody]string activation_code)
        {
            if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(activation_code))
            {
                string decode_token = HttpUtility.UrlDecode(activation_code); ;
                string token_string = Crypto.Decrypt(activation_code, passPhrase);

                if (token_string != null)
                {
                    User activateAcc = db.Users.Where(user => user.ConfirmToken == token_string).SingleOrDefault();
                    if (activateAcc != null)
                    {
                        activateAcc.IsActive = true;

                        try
                        {
                            db.SaveChanges();
                            var credential = new UserCredential(); 
                            credential.EmailAddress = activateAcc.UserMail; 
                            credential.Password = activateAcc.UserPassword;

                            return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, credential);
                        }
                        catch
                        {
                            return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.Ambiguous, "cannot confirm account");
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.NotAcceptable, "invalid account");
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.NoContent, "invalid token data");
                }
            }
            else
            {
                return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.NoContent, "missing activation code");
            }
        }
```

The problem is when the controller fire the request is made but without sending any data to the server. The `[FromBody]string activation_code`is null

Comment: Not sure, but I think your data in the request should be another JS object: `$http({method:"post", url:activationLink, data: {activation_code:activation_code}}).success(function(response){..`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Wrap your parameter in quotes:

```
$http({method:"post", url:activationLink, data: '"' + activation_code + '"'});
```

**Explanation**

For Web API to bind to a simple string primitive, the body must be specified as:

"some string here"

For example:

```
POST http://localhost:5076/api/values HTTP/1.1
 User-Agent: Fiddler
 Host: localhost:5076
 Content-Type: application/json
 Content-Length: 7

 "Alice"
```

The quotes are important.  For more information, check this [article](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/formats-and-model-binding/parameter-binding-in-aspnet-web-api).